# Issue with MVVM view first approach

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am using mvvm architecture view first approach in my project. I mean I have view-viewmodel binding defined in resource file.
But i'm unable to open multiple instances of same view...If I open the the new viewmodel will refer to the first view.

Comment: a concrete example and code would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting

```
x:Shared="false"
```

Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx)

Comment: No, its always been their! AFIK

Answer (score 0):

WPF initializes data templates as singletons by default. You can override this behavior by using the *x:Shared=false* setting. Note: This works only with compiled resource files.

A more flexible option is to use an **IoC Container** for creating the associated View for a ViewModel. You might have a look at the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)** which shows how this works by using the Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) as an IoC Container.