# Can not locate x:Shared in wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Please look into this question.

[Issue with MVVM view first approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795737/issue-with-mvvm-view-first-approach)

But I'm unable to find "x:Shared" attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx) is the msdn link. it works in 3.5 also see below.

From the Book WPF Unleased:
    Assuming the Conventional x Namespace Prefix.
    x:Shared --> Attribute on any element in a ResourceDictionary, but only works if XAML is compiled!

```
//ResourceDictionary
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:x="http://schema.microsoft.con/winfx/2006/xaml>
<Image x:Shared="False" x:Key="zoom" Height="21" Source="zoom.png" />
...
```

Comment: I guess, you mention about xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml". But I'm unable to see x:Shared                                               http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vswpfdesigner/thread/15885852-ebeb-4794-95b9-304076a81fae

Comment: what happens if you just type x:Shared=True and then compile? did it not work? what framework do you use? if you have blend what happens there?